# Select element value is not binding because of type mismatch in angularjs 1.4

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a ng-model and it is assigned a value but it is not binding with selected element.

```
<select data-ng-model="myval">
  <option value="? number:2 ?"></option>
  <option value="2" class="ng-binding">Value 1</option>
  <option value="3" class="ng-binding">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

in the above code snippet  number:2 is generated because myval is assigned to 2 and
I noticed that it is because of type mismatch. My question is how will we give value in option tag with type number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "? number:2 ?". Whatever it is, you should consider using ng-value there instead.

Comment: @Mohair number:2 is the value for may ng-model variable myval  and there is no change if i use ng-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the `ng-options` directive instead of a custom select with an `ng-repeat` and many `ng-value`

If you have something like this :

```
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, title: 'key #1' },
    { id: 2, title: 'key #2' }
];
```

Then you should do :

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.title for item in items"></select>
```

You will get :

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.title for item in items">
    <option value="key #1"></option>
    <option value="key #2"></option>
</select>
```

And the binding will allow you to do :

```
console.log($scope.selected); // { id: 2, name: 'key #2' }
```

You can find an example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpKKaW

Comment: I know about ng-options but want to know how can we do that with options why because we need to filter the large list to get only required options.